# Ext JS 4: Unable to display the date from record in the 'datefield'

Tags: extjs4.1

I am trying to load the record in the form. One of the field type is 'datefield' and have a field in record in milliseconds.

parital record data:

```
topAccount:"ALPINE"
tradeDate:1360167174553
tradeId:"2110720401"
```

and the view is

```
 xtype: 'datefield',
 name: 'tradeDate',
 itemId: 'tradeDate',
 margin: 8,
 fieldLabel: 'Trade Date:',
 renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y/m/d'),
```

But, when the form is loaded with record, I get empty field.

Can someone help me on this problem?

Thanks
Tharahan

Answer (score 5):

`1360167174553` is not a valid date for this purpose. `1920-12-01T13:00` is.

If you look at the [Date datatype](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Types.html#Ext-data-Types), you'll see:

```
    DATE: {
        convert: function(v) {
            var df = this.dateReadFormat || this.dateFormat,
                parsed;

            if (!v) {
                return null;
            }
            if (Ext.isDate(v)) {
                return v;
            }
            if (df) {
                return Ext.Date.parse(v, df);
            }

            parsed = Date.parse(v);
            return parsed ? new Date(parsed) : null;
        },
        sortType: st.asDate,
        type: 'date'
    }
});
```

With a number, `Ext.isDate()` will fail. Then both `Ext.Date.parse` and `Date.parse` expect a string, the tokens of which do not support just milliseconds.

If you insist using milliseconds try this:

```
Ext.define('YourModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'tradeDate',  dateFormat: 'u' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is valid date. If I do Ext.getCmp('tradeDate').setValue(new Date(record.data.tradeDate)); then you get the correct date.

Comment: If you insist using milliseconds, have a look at the model's [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) option - just convert it to date object using `new date()`. I've edited my answer to show you how.

Comment: Or you can try have `dateFormat: 'u'` in your model definition for `tradeDate`.